# Error when uploading files to the Nextcloud via Python wrapper for NextCloud api

Tags: python, file-upload, nextcloud

I use [Python wrapper for NextCloud api](https://github.com/matejak/nextcloud-API) in order to upload file from my local storage to Nextcloud:

```
file_name = "12.txt"
file_local_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file_name)
a=nxc.upload_file("my_uid",file_local_path,"Test/")
print(a)
```

but I get an error:

```
<OCSResponse: Status: Failed>
```

Then I add file name to Nextcloud path:

```
file_name = "12.txt"
file_local_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file_name)
a=nxc.upload_file("my_uid",file_local_path,"Test/12.txt")
print(a)
```

and I get success message:

```
<OCSResponse: Status: OK>
```

but uploaded file (12.txt) on Nextcloud is empty, while my file contains some text.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. And what is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the new python package from the community called [nc_py_api](https://github.com/cloud-py-api/nc_py_api) for this.

Example for your task:

```
from nc_py_api import Nextcloud

nc = Nextcloud(nextcloud_url="https://nextcloud.local", nc_auth_user="admin", nc_auth_pass="admin")
with open("12.txt") as f:
    nc.files.upload_stream("remote_name.txt", f)
```

This will use chunked upload and not require much memory for large files.

Comment: Thank you! It will be useful for my script!

Answer (score 0):

Considering the [samples provided](https://github.com/matejak/nextcloud-API/blob/master/tests/test_webdav.py) for this API, you have to provide the file name, not just the parent directory:

```
return self.nxc_local.upload_file(self.user_username, file_local_path, file_name)
```

Secondly, you say that you are trying to upload `12.txt` but you code shows `12.jpg`. Perhaps you have mistyped? If that is the case, you could be trying to open a `12.jpg` that doesn't exist and therefore the file in the cloud is empty. In any case, take a look at the [API reference](https://nextcloud-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_wrappers.html?highlight=upload_file#nextcloud.api_wrappers.WebDAV.upload_file) as well as the provided [samples](https://github.com/matejak/nextcloud-API/tree/master/tests) to solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, I try to upload txt file in my code. I enter jpg format just only for my question and this is incorrect